# Blocking mysite.elasticbeanstalk URLs from public

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have 3 elastic beanstalk environments under the same application, which I'm deploying a .NET MVC site to

- **Environment name** | **Current EB URL** | **Public cname set externally**
- MySite-Green | mysite-live.elasticbeanstalk.com | mysite.com
- MySite-Blue | mysite-staging.elasticbeanstalk.com | n/a
- MySite-Testing | mysite-testing.elasticbeanstalk.com | n/a

I need to achieve the following:

#### mysite-live.elasticbeanstalk.com

- Environment accessible via **mysite.com* publically.
- Environment accessible via mysite-live.elasticbeanstalk.com from certain IP ranges only

#### mysite-staging.elasticbeanstalk.com

- Environment accessible via mysite-staging.elasticbeanstalk.com from certain IP ranges only

#### mysite-testing.elasticbeanstalk.com

- Environment accessible via mysite-testing.elasticbeanstalk.com from certain IP ranges only

I also need to be able to switch the urls between live and staging environments to change which one is live to the public (so that google doesn't crawl it).

The testing environment I've locked down on the load balancer security group, so that should be covered.

How can I achieve this? Or is there a better way of just making sure the elasticbeanstalk urls are not indexed?

Answer (score -1):

You can create your Elastic Beanstalk environments in a VPC.
Read more about this here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo-vpc.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Introduction.html

Comment: My environments are in a VPC, but I need one to be available to the public on a non-beanstalk URL. I don't think a VPC can solve this can it?